# I need to select records based on the value of a column in the same table.

Tags: sql

I have a table called user_versions. This table doesn't have any identity column due to the requirements. If a user updates their details a new version is created, a columns called version is incremented by 1 and the other version isn't live anymore but is kept again this is due to requirements and the new version goes live.

```
**My Problem**  
Simple example

user_versions
------------
user_id|name|email|version
1|John|john@example.com|1
1|John|john@example.com|2
1|John|john@example.com|3
1|John|john@example.com|4
2|Peter|peter@example.com|1
2|Peter|peter@example.com|2
2|Peter|peter@example.com|3

Needed Results!!!
------------
1|John|john@example.com|4
2|Peter|peter@example.com|3
```

If I wanted to return the newest version of every how could I do so? I've tried a lot of stuff and can't figure it out. I am able to do so with two separate queries but I would really appreciate if I could return the needed in one query.

Any help at all would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With standard syntax it would be:

```
select uv.* 
from user_versions uv
inner join(select user_id, max(version) as version 
           from user_versions 
           group by user_id) as t 
   on uv.user_id = t.user_id and 
      uv.version = t.version
```

Comment: Thank you found this easy and great to follow.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte as
(
select user_id,name,email,version, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by version desc) as rn
from
user_versions)
select user_id,name, email, version from cte
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple

```
SELECT user_id,name,email,max(version)

FROM user_versions.tt
group by user_id,name,email
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT user_id, name, email, version
 FROM (
        SELECT user_id, name, email, version, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY version DESC) AS rank
        FROM user_versions) uv 
 WHERE uv.rank = 1
```